# If don't respect even if the inner value it is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, dom

This is my HTML code:

```js
$(function() {
  function reverse(s) {
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
  }

  $('button').click(function() {
    var span = $(this).siblings('span');
    span.text(function() {
      var reversed = reverse($(this).text());
      return reversed;
    });

    if (!span.children('small').length) {
      span.wrapInner('<small></small>');
      console.log(!span.children('small').length);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>reverse1</span>
<span>reverse2</span>
<button>reverse me</button>
```

I put a console.log into the if statement to add a small only once in the DOM (not sure about wrapInner function) the check if the small node is added only once. I checked the value in the logical expression is true where there is no small tag and false when it's added. Can anyone help me to understand?

Comment: No, it keeps printing the false value even if the small tag has already added...

Comment: You remove the small tag every time you re-run the text() call. It completely removes all the content of the given span and replaces it with the reversed string.

Comment: So if I got the issue, I need to check if in the span there is a textnode before to change it, do I?

Comment: console.log(!2);

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Well, if you look at the DOM structure after you've clicked that button a dozen times, you'll see it only has the one small. Exactly what is the problem?

Comment: I want to add the wrap a small the first time and after only reverse the text inside the span. It a chunck of code in a plugin I'm creating.

Comment: So than you should wrap it first and than select the small elements and replace the text

Comment: Snowmonkey: I had suspicious about...thanks

Comment: @Salvio, if it worked for you, upvote and accept! lol

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my code to create a small within your span if one doesn't exist, and to place the text content of the span within that small. It only creates the small ON THE FIRST PASS. All subsequent passes simply empty the small and refill it. I really don't need to empty the small in the IF statement, simply demonstrating that you can work with it either way.

```js
$(function() {
  function reverse(s) {
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
  }
  // When the button el is clicked, reverse
  $('button').click(function() {
    var span = $(this).siblings('span');

    span.each(function() {
      // Store the text string, regardless of DOM
      var textStr = $(this).text();

      if (!$(this).children("small").length) {
        // I don't have a nested small. Make one!
        //  Note that, in making one, I wipe out any
        //  content in this span element.
        console.log("No small!");
        $(this).html("<small></small");
      } else {
        // I have a small. Don't wipe the entire contents
        //   of this span, simply empty the small.
        console.log("Has small!");
        $(this).children("small").empty();
      };
      
      // Either way, I now have a span with an empty small.
      //  Stick my text in there!
      $(this).children("small").text(reverse(textStr));
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>reverse1</span>
  <span>reverse2</span>
  <button>reverse me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is the problem. I commented this part of code after you advised me and it had a small and never execute the if stament...thanks again...

Comment: If you want the button click to create the small el, it's really not a problem -- simply change the logic just a little. I've edited my code to create it after the first click, then populate it on each subsequent click.